# Grey background toolbar C++

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, styles, toolbar

I am trying to create a toolbar in C++ using Win32 API (no MFC or VC++). I am able to create a toolbar which looks like this and has no background, just the basic window color.

[image]

I would like it to look like picture below with the glossy bar and a grey gradiant

[image]

I have tried using `TBSTYLE_FLAT` when I got an undefined error, I declared it as equal to `0x0800` which still did not make any difference. Do I need to add more properties? I will paste my code below.

```
HWND hTbar = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 0, 0, hwnd, (HMENU)12, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
        SendMessage(hTbar, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);

        TBBUTTON tb[5];
        TBADDBITMAP tBmp;

        tBmp.hInst =  HINST_COMMCTRL;
        tBmp.nID = IDB_STD_SMALL_COLOR;
        SendMessage(hTbar, TB_ADDBITMAP, 0, (LPARAM)&tBmp);
        ZeroMemory(tb, sizeof(tb));

        tb[0].iBitmap = STD_FILEOPEN;
        tb[0].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
        tb[0].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;

        SendMessage(hTbar, TB_ADDBUTTONS, sizeof(tb)/sizeof(TBBUTTON), (LPARAM)&tb);
```

I am using Windows 7 and the Win32 C++ API. Thanks.

Comment: Does your app have the [common controls manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: Yup. I have shiny Windows-7-like buttons on my application.

Comment: Use Spy++ to see what styles it has set; I suppose it is possible that it is custom drawn as well.  Or it could be part of the theme data.

Answer (score 0):

The background probably comes from the parent window. To get the visual style background gradient effect for free, put your toolbar inside a [rebar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774375%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and use the TBSTYLE_FLAT and TBSTYLE_TRANSPARENT toolbar styles.

Comment: I am using `WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | TBSTYLE_TRANSPARENT | TBSTYLE_FLAT` for the properties of the toolbar. I am getting `TBSTYLE_FLAT is not declared in this scope.` same for TBSTYLE_ TRANSPARENT.

Comment: @coolcoder: You might want to fix your headers before you move on, you can't code without proper header files...

Comment: What header should I add? I am including `commctrl.h windows.h`

Comment: @coolcoder: You need to set #define _WIN32_IE 0x0300 probably